# iOS anti-injection method

Tags: ios, security

As we known, some tools based on Cydiasubstrate or Cycript can inject dylib into normal apps to cheat or do something else. As a developer, I don't want to have an injection dylib in my normal iOS app. So I want to check dylib which running in my current process.(And need all method can pass apple's check.)

I only have one way to detect dylib injection is checking getenv("DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES"). So, are there other ways to detect evil dylib?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Just like jailbreak detection itself, asserting that "MobileSubstrate is evil" is bull****. If you are afraid of piracy, then put crack detection in your code, or, even better, make an app that's worth paying for.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry, you misunderstand my point about my goal. I also know substrate or cycript just a toolkit, but some cheaters will use those toolkits to cheat. And jailbreak is not consistent to piracy. I want to build a fair opportunity game world. So I don't care about the jailbreak or piracy, but cheater who I'm very hated. And English is not my first language, sorry about inaccurate words.